# How mount multiple cifs shares with diferents kerberos tickets

Tags: linux, mount, kerberos

I want to mount two resources on linux using kerberos authentication. The user who performs the mounts in both cases is root. But I want to mount resource1 using a kerberos ticket from user1 and resource2 using another kerberos ticket from user2.

The linux system is not in domain. The distribution is Rocky Linux.

I have tried to do the mounts by modifying the environment variable krb5ccname, but it seems that cifs.upcall ignores the value of it.

The mount must be done at system boot, if it can be done with the fstab better, if not with a script.

After several tests I managed to mount the two resources with different users by following these steps

- `kinit user1@DOM.LOCAL` -> generate a ticket in the keyring
- `mount //server/share1 /mnt/aux1 -o sec=krb5i` -> mounts with the id of user1
- `kinit user2@DOM.LOCAL` -> generates another ticket in the keyring
- `mount //server/share2 /mnt/aux2 -o sec=krb5i` -> mount with user2 id

But this way I don't know how it will behave when it's time to renew the tickets.

Is there any way to tell the mount command which kerberos ticket to use for authentication?

is it possible to use kerberos tickets in docker containers too?

Thanks!!